# PyMongo: Update, $multi:false, get _id of updated document?

Tags: python, multithreading, mongodb, pymongo

When updating a document in MongoDB using a search-style update, is it possible to get back the _id of the document(s) updated?

For example:

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client.test_database
col = db.test_col

col.insert({'name':'kevin', 'status':'new'})
col.insert({'name':'brian', 'status':'new'})
col.insert({'name':'matt', 'status':'new'})
col.insert({'name':'stephen', 'status':'new'})

info = col.update({'status':'new'}, {'$set':{'status':'in_progress'}}, multi=False)
print info
# {u'updatedExisting': True, u'connectionId': 1380, u'ok': 1.0, u'err': None, u'n': 1}
# I want to know the _id of the document that was updated.
```

I have multiple threads accessing the database collection and want to be able to mark a document as being acted upon. Getting the document first and then updating by Id is not a good answer, because two threads may "get" the same document before it is updated. The application is a simple asynchronous task queue (yes, I know we'd be better off with something like Rabbit or ZeroMQ for this, but adding to our stack isn't possible right now).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`pymongo.collection.find_and_modify`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_and_modify). It is a wrapper around MongoDB [findAndModify](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/#findandmodify) command and can return original (by default) or modified document.

```
info = col.find_and_modify({'status':'new'}, {'$set':{'status':'in_progress'}})
if info:
    print info.get('_id')
```